# ntaxa for phyloseq - remove ASVs that sum to 0

Tags: r, bioconductor, phyloseq

I have subset a large phyloseq object from 2000 to only 29 samples. When I put in ntaxa for the new phyloseq object, it gives me >4000 taxa, which is the number from my original phyloseq. How do I remove ASVs that are not present in the new object so I only count the ASVs that are actually present?